# Android pop-up menu with icons (similar to Google Map app version 6)

Tags: android, menu, popup

Does anyone know what component is used for the menu in the new version 6 of Google Map’s official app on Android?

I’m trying to build a menu similar to that, couldn’t find anything in the official dev pages (Note: I’m targeting Gingerbread APIs, possibly with backward compatibility up to 1.6.)

Here is the only picture I found of this menu (this is on ICS, but something similar is displayed on Gingerbread). Please have a look at the left screenshot here (from the [Gizmodo](https://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2011/11/google-maps-6-0-for-android-updates-with-indoor-maps-and-places-homescreen/) site):

[image: from Gizmodo]

If there’s no built-in component, what approach would you follow to build one?

At worst, if no such component exist for Android 2.x, do you know whether the Google Map application itself is open-source, and where to find its source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look into following link. There is an good  examples of Quick Action dialog.So you can modify the code for whatever you want.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Thanks, interesting. It's not exactly what I'm looking for (I may have a large number of icons, so I'd prefer a vertical list with a scrollbar) but I'm sure I can modify it. Will have a look.

Comment: Actually there is an example with vertical layout, so it might just work for me ;)

Comment: I took inspiration from this, and it works perfectly. It's also very flexible and customizable, I love it, thanks again for the link.

Comment: Actually used to use this before, but I occasionally had issues with the menu being concealed by the keyboard.

Comment: How to customize the menu layout?

Answer (score 11):

This should work down to API 4 (but not tested, YMMV). For example:

[image: An example]

If you are using ActionBarSherlock, you can use the `IcsListPopupWindow` class. Set up some properties on it in onCreate. You'll need to subclass an ArrayAdapter as well.

**in onCreate():**

```
mPopupMenu = new IcsListPopupWindow(getContext());
mAdapter = new PopupMenuAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourArrayOfPopupMenuItems);
mPopupMenu.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPopupMenu.setModal(true);
mPopupMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);
mPopupMenu.setOnDismissListener(this); // only if you need it
```

**Inner classes within your fragment/activity:**

```
private class PopupMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PopupMenuItem> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    PopupMenuItem data[] = null;

    public PopupMenuAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, PopupMenuItem[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        // initialize a view first
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        PopupMenuItem pItem = data[position];
        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setText(pItem.textResId);
        text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(pItem.iconResId, 0, 0, 0);

        return view;
    }
}

// ... PopupMenuItem is just a container

private static class PopupMenuItem {
    public int iconResId;
    public int textResId;

    public PopupMenuItem(int iconResId, int textResId) {
        this.iconResId = iconResId;
        this.textResId = textResId;
    }
}
```

**Whenever you need to show it** (such as in a a `View.OnClickListener`)

```
mPopupMenu.setContentWidth(getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2);
PopupAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // if you change anything
mPopupMenu.setAnchorView(yourAnchorView);
mPopupMenu.show();
```

**In your OnItemClickListener**

Make sure to call `mPopupMenu.dismiss()`!

Hope this helps! And thanks to Jake Wharton for ABS!

Comment: thanks for sharing. In your code, is mPopupMenu the same as mPopupWindow? My main question is how to set the AnchorView to a MenuItem on the action bar - so what is 'overflow' in your code above?

Comment: just updated my answer... overflow was just the view to which you want the menu to attach

Comment: @OlegVaskevich you forgot to call show(). also, how do you make the items look as nice as on the apinner or other examples, and how do you make it close the popup when you click outside of it?

Comment: I'll have to dig up some old code to see how I did it. If I remember correctly, you can just specify your own layout ID in the adapter's constructor, and the popup would automatically close when it lost focus -- at least with the above properties in place.

Comment: Edited my answer. Guess I did not include `show()` in my answer here--thanks. Personally I used android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, but you can use another layout if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

[`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) is probably what you are looking for. However, it only works on Android 3.0+ (introduced in API Level 11) and it's not present in the compatibility library as far as I know.

Comment: So what you're saying is the version of the menu that is displayed on Android 2.xx is a completely custom menu? Any chance of finding how they did that and stealing bits of the code from Google? ;)

Comment: Just checked, it's definitely in the Ice Cream Sandwich source *(as expected)*. Which means that you can download it and see if you can backport this component. You can find it under `frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/PopupMenu.java`.

Comment: @alextsc thanks, I'm gonna try that, I already have the ICS source ready for browsing :)

Comment: I usually don't have a copy of the source locally, I prefer browsing it online. I tried searching for `PopupMenu` on Google code search but [came up with no results](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=file:android/widget/PopupMenu.java). How could that be? Is their index *really* outdated?

Comment: My android SDK which is synced to the latest API 15 seems to have the source file PopupMenu.java. Have you tried to search in your SDK? I would not be surprised though if it pulls tons of dependencies.

Comment: PopupMenu works for me. But the problem with this is i am unable to add icon

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a customized action bar. Probably an [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider).
The ActionBar is available since API level 11, but check out [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).