# what is the name of this widget and how can i use it in my app?

Tags: android-widget, android

I want to know what is the name of this widget  , and how to use it in my app, i've already see it in some apps in the Android market, but i don't know what is it's name and how to use it in some activity of my app .

[image: the widget surrounded with red rectangle]

Regards ,

Houcine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8326152/1101070) answer, I believe it's called the **Quick Action Dialog** and you can read about it and implement it from:

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

It's called QuickContactBadge.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html

I don't know it's recommended to use it now after honeycomb and ICS. Don't see those UI on HC or ICS now.

Comment: I think this is still valid, however; it doesn't show up anymore because the UI functionality has changed. They got rid of context menus and now use hotbars.

Comment: i've see this widget on a Galaxy S 1 , and galaxy S II ;)

Comment: Yep, this is available on 2.2(I guess) up till pre-HC and pre-ICS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [android-segmentedradiobutton](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton), a port of the iPhone [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.)

[image: screenshot of android-segmentedradiobutton from github]

Comment: Nope. It's some sort of a "popup" (pop-down?) that appears after clicking, with a bunch of options. I've seen something similar in the Google Maps app as well.

Comment: yep , and i've seen it in the app "Jours Fériés" , it is used to choose a country . and i want to know what is this widget, or at least, what standard widget i should customize to get a widget like that one :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a custom widget, not in the standard Android SDK :(