# Make a spinner-like dropdown box from a button?

Tags: android, menu, popup, android-spinner

I was trying to figure out how to create this style used in Google Now, how the "Settings" appears to be a Spinner drop-down box but does not use the typical `Spinner` design:
[image: Beautiful design ahoy!]

Any ideas/suggestions on how to emulate this?
Thanks!

Comment: That looks just like the overflow button used in the Action Bar.

Comment: It's designed to look like that to stay true to the design standard that Settings is in fact "overflow" from the main purpose of the Card, but each Card is not its own separate Activity so it wouldn't have an Action Bar. This is some custom implementation of a Spinner but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called pop up menu. It is implemented in apidemos for example.

Did you look at the example of ApiDemos->Views->popup menu. This may be appropriate. Attached screenshot for your reference. Pop up menu is available since API 11. Ref.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

or

This could be useful too

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiAOg.png

You can get the Library from: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

or

If you want to display icon along with menu items then I recommend to visit this post,
Please refer to this solution [stackoverflow.com/a/11765787/1143977](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11765787/1143977)

[image: Pop up menu]

Comment: In reference to your edit - I actually use ActionBarSherlock but I would like that Spinner Dropdown thing to be dropped down from an ImageView. I haven't figured out a way to do that yet. As for the first post I'll have to look into that. I can't believe I didn't think to look at the APIDemos. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: I think API demo display menu on button but that could very well be done from ImageView.  I think you will find your answer from the APIDemos.

Comment: You are correct! It works perfectly with any View subclass. I wish I could give you bonus Internet Points for this, but is there a way to make the icons appear with it too? Each MenuItem in the XML has an icon attribute, but they're not appearing. Any ideas? If not, that's fine you've already done enough!

Comment: For your issue with icon, you may have to make custom pop up menu. Please refer to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765787/1143977