# Adding menu button to ActionBar Tab

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a menu button to the right side of the a ActionBar tab area
[image]

Of course what I really need is a clickable Image/button that is always aligned to the right but I'm not sure how can I do it *without* major hacking to ActionBar or writing one my self. 
Is there a standard way to do it with ActionBar?

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE** For those who suggested to use the standard way of adding a menu, this is what happens

[image]

Thanks
Yoni

Comment: android handle that, you just set menu to your layout. I think this handled in +4.0

Comment: for > 11 API read comment above. < 11 API http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765787/1168654

Comment: That not seems to be the case, using android build in options a menu is created but appears beneath the tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can *force* the OS to put menu button in action bar but that **isn't a good idea**. Let the OS decide when to put the menu button on ActionBar.

Anyway I do it like this:

```
           try {
                ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
                Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
                if(menuKeyField != null) {
                    menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                    menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("yourapp", ex.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. A working solution only for devices with hardware button is not good for me but maybe it will lead me to a solution.

Comment: Try it, it works for non hardware button devices as well

Comment: I might have missed something. It places the menu under the Tabs (see the second image I attached to the the question)

Comment: You are saying putting menu button on ActionBar. This code does this